# Is Using HTML5 canvas a good idea for Electron.JS?

Tags: electron

I want to make an electron app that is similar to scratch in which it uses drag and drop features. I want to make these features using canvas. However, I don't know if this is a good idea as I tried searching it up and never got Electron and HTML5 Canvas in the same sentence.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Do you get an error? Of course you can use Canvas in Electron since it's built on Chromium, it has everything that Chormium has. Just try it

Comment: Electron renderer is kinda Chromium, so all browser API will be available. Feel free to use any web methods at this Electron

Answer (score 0):

I'm using canvas for rendering charts in my project and it works correctly. I have been researching a bit and I have not found any better alternative to replace it